# A soma dos N primeiros números primos

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

> Escreva um programa que leia um inteiro não negativo e imprima a soma dos N primeiros números primos.

Não estou conseguindo somar os N primeiros números primos e sim somar até o número primo digitado.

Se eu digitar 5 por exemplo aparece 2 3 5 e a soma que é 10. Mas no caso teria que aparecer 2 3 5 7 11 e a soma que daria 28.

Meu código:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número inteiro positico: '))
soma = 0
for num in range(2, n + 1):
    primo = True
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
           primo = False
    if primo:
        print(num)
        soma += num
print(soma)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número inteiro positivo: '))
soma = 0
conta = 0
num = 2
while conta < n:
    primo = True
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
           primo = False
           break
    if primo:
        print(num)
        soma += num
        conta += 1
    num += 1
print(soma)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3lx17t). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bqcjtkjp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/SumPrimes.py).

A contagem de quantos números são primos. e portanto somados. deve ser independente da evolução dos números que são considerados primos. O código da pergunta está parando quando o número que pode ser primo chega no limite. Então `num` evoluirá em cada passo como o código está fazendo, mas a contagem de quantos está pegando é a condição para termino das repetições.

Daria para usar só `for` mas teria que por um `if`, não vi vantagem.